# PHP captcha - help

Tags: php, captcha

I'm using securimage to generate captchas. (http://www.phpcaptcha.org/)

I have the following code to verify a captcha:

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once('./securimage.php');
$securimage = new Securimage();

echo "Entered: ".$_GET['captcha']."<br>\n";

if($securimage->check($_GET['captcha'])==false){
  echo "captcha invalid";
}else{
  echo "OK";
}
?>
```

The problem is, when I visit the url (http://109.123.109.205/lib/securimage/verify.php?captcha=z6fega), it keeps returning "captcha invalid"!

Here is the captcha image url: http://109.123.109.205/lib/securimage/securimage_show.php

I hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: It must do because the captcha echos correctly on the page

Comment: Can you post the contents of the secureimage.php file?

Comment: secureimage.php available at http://109.123.109.205/lib/securimage/securimage.php.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a session_start() problem, can you change to `var_dump(session_start());` to make sure it's working?

Otherwise I'd be surprised if there was a problem with the library, but there's little else that could be wrong.

**Update**

I think you need to actually create a page that uses securimage_show.php in an img tag, and call `session_start();` at the top.

Ie.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<html>
<head><title>Captcha check</title></head>
<body>
<img src="securimage_show.php" />
<form method="get" action="verify.php">
<input type="text" name="captcha" />
<input type="submit" value="Verfiy" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I dump the session_start(), I get "bool(true)"

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. There is some problem in your securimage.php (your lib)

Comment: Do you really think there's a problem in a published library?

Comment: Every published library has a problem or two... that's normal. But in this case I don't think it's the reason for your problems.

Comment: Do you think there might be some PHP configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem - if you put in the domain name instead of the ip address, it works ;)